# How to passing json parameters for test api (restful) in katalon studio?

Tags: testing, groovy, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I created a demo test using reqres.in fake data API. 
I want to create a user with a name and a job parameter, but the data format required is json.

[image]

In my Katalon test I tried to do that in the script tab:

[image]

My parameters are not sent to the API...

I didn't find how to do that in Katalon Studio (5.7) and I don't know if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i 've found a solution, for exemple i want to get a new token with a refresh_token_key, and send it in json format and modify my request object.

I get my refresh_token_ken, put it in a string variable, get my request object and modify the body like this :

```
    RequestObject roRefresh_Token = findTestObject('Authentication/Refresh Token');

    def jsonStr = "{'RefreshToken':'"+GlobalVariable.Refresh_Token+"'}";

    roRefresh_Token.setBodyContent(new HttpTextBodyContent(jsonStr, "UTF-8", "application/json"));

    WS.sendRequest(roRefresh_Token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add parameters to the REST object.

Click the `+ Add` button shown in the screenshot and add the following to the parameter table:

```
Name    |  Value
--------------------
name    |  ${name}
job     |  ${job}
```

That will change your request to `https://reqres.in/api/users?name=${name}&job=${job}` so when you send the request as you did in the OP, `Ema` and `developer` will go to the place of the placeholders for `name` and `job`.

Comment: Thanks, i 've already tested this but, the data sened is not json format and the api doesn't respond if it's not json paramters